# In QnA Maker is there a way to preserve edited QnA pairs, so that they don't get overwritten when doing a "Refresh" import?

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

My scenario is that our marketing department have various (FAQ related) URL's , each of which contains approximately 20 question and answer pairs, per URL.

I have imported these URL's into QnA maker and (importantly) the marketing department have finessed and tidied the answers held in the knowledge base (* reason below)

The marketing department still use a process where they add new question and answers to the relevant URL when needed, so - for example URL "X" might contain 20 Question and Answer pairs currently , all of which have been imported (and tidied/finessed) in the KB.

They want to add a new question and answer pair to the URL (i.e. make the change on the website), and then they want to "Refresh" that URL into the Knowledge Base. The problem is (I believe), that the original 20 question and answers pairs on the web url will actually over-write the "finessed" ones in the KB.

Is there any way to avoid this? Ideally just (somehow) bring in the "newly added" Question and Answer pair? (without having to copy/paste the content from the web to the KB?)

(*)the reason this needed doing was simply that, on the source URL's the answers were quite verbose, and included images, which work fine on the actual website, but when these answers are imported , they didn't look elegant within the bot , so they have been edited (within QnA maker) so they now look good when yielded by the bot)

Answer (score 0):

Importing URLs into QnA Maker that only contain new content will always overwrite a knowledgebase with the content found within. This is true whether that is from doc linked from a URL, an uploaded doc, or some other method. If you are wanting to add new questions to an existing knowledgebase, then you first need to export that KB, make updates to the content contained within it (i.e. add your new questions to the old), and then upload/provide a link to that new data set.

If you are wanting to do this via REST API, then you should look over the [QnA Maker REST API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices-qnamaker/) docs. By using calls like GET, LIST, and UPDATE, you should be able to achieve what you are wanting to do. There are [samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-REST-api-samples) you can reference, as well, to help you on your way.

Comment: Thanks @stevenkanberg - I would have upvoted, but I dont yet have enough reputation